# Uppercase Booleans in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: php, netbeans-8, psr-2

When I using netbeans 8.2 for PHP code, it always give

> NULL FALSE TRUE

in uppercase. But PSR-2 tells us

> The PHP constants true, false, and null MUST be in lower case.

How I can change it, and netbeabs give it in lowercase

Comment: is this any help? I do not use netbeans myself, forgive me if it's useless :) https://github.com/allebb/netbeans-psr-formatting

Comment: @Dale thanks for suggestion, but I want it work in netbeans autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it's help somebody, who using netbeans, and want have PHP constant

> NULL FALSE TRUE

in lowercase for autocomplete.

Click Ctrl + i, in Find window type NULL and open file

netbeans-8.2/php/phpstubs/phpruntime/Core.php

and here I change value for lowercase.